# How can I send a message to my akka actor system's event stream without addressing the message to any actor in particular?

Tags: scala, events, stream, akka

I'm interested in implementing:
 1. an akka actor `A` that sends messages to an event stream;
 2. an akka actor `L` that listens to messages of a certain type that have been published on the event stream.

If possible, I would like to reutilize the actor system's event stream.

I know how to do 2. It is explained here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/event-bus.html#event-stream

But how can I do 1?

I know how to make `A` send a message addressed to another actor(Ref), but I do not want to address the message to any particular actor(Ref). I just want the message to appear in the event stream and be picked up by whoever is listening to messages of that type. Is this possible somehow?

A side-question: if I implement 2 as described in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/event-bus.html#event-stream, does the listener know who sent the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation link that you posted you can publish messages to the EventStream:

```
system.eventStream.publish(Jazz("Sonny Rollins"))
```

Message will be delivered to all actors that subscribed themselves to this message type:

```
system.eventStream.subscribe(jazzListener, classOf[Jazz])
```

For the subscribers to know the sender, I suggest you define an ActorRef field in your payload and the sending actor can put its self reference in it when publishing the message. NB Defining the sender's ActorRef explicitly in the message type is how the new [akka-typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/typed/actors.html) library deals with all actor interactions, so it's a good idea to get used to this pattern.